# React and React Router - Home page component not rendering after Build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am new to React and React Router and have been having some issues after I "compile" my app and try to run it on my server. 
Background: I used create-react-app to start this project and have been developing in VS Code, when I run "npm run start", everything is showing correctly in the browser window running on localhost:3000. When I run "npm run build" it compiles my files into a build folder. When I put the files of that folder into my WebContent folder on my WildFly server, I don't get the content for the home page.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const User = ({match}) => {
  return (<h1>Welcome User {match.params.username}</h1>)
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
      <ul>
      <li>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
        <Link to="/users">User</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
        <Route path ="/" exact render={
          () => {
            return (<h1>Welcome Home</h1>);
          }
        }/>
        <Route path ="/about" exact render={
          () => {
            return (<h1>About</h1>);
          }
        }/>
        <Route path ="/user/:username" exact component={User} />
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I land on localhost:8080, I should be seeing the "Welcome Home" text, but all I am seeing are the buttons to switch pages. This is just a test project for React Router. I am looking to use something similar to this for a larger project, but I need to home page to render correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the URL of your live page?

Comment: By buttons, do you mean the Link tags you have in your code are visible?

Comment: Yes by buttons I meant the Link tags, sorry about that.

Comment: As for the live page, I don not have a live page currently, but I could serve up my page if that would help. I am confused by this behavior because I am following the tutorial from the react-router here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exact` in about and user route.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by incorporating the hash router. This wasn't the best solution as it adds a hash(#) into the url, but my pages would render running on a Wildfly server, so I am happy